# Issue with freeing the returned wchar_t array | Actually, I wanna get the application path without ‘name.exe’

Tags: arrays, c, free, wchar-t

The purpose of my function is to return the path of the application, so without the `name of the application.exe`. For this I use `GetModuleFileName`, copy all characters up to the last `\` into an allocated array, and finally return this array. Back in the main function, I have the problem that `free()` doesn't work. Also, maybe there is a much simpler way for what I am trying to do.

I'm using Visual Studio CE 2019, it's a C++ console application, but the file is called Main.c and the compilation type is "compile as C Code".

```
wchar_t* ApplicationPath()
{
    wchar_t buffer[PathLength] = { '\0' };
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, PathLength);
    int cnt1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < PathLength; i++)
    {   
        if (buffer[i] == '\0')
        {
            break;
        }
        if (buffer[i] == '\\')
        {
            cnt1 = i;
        }   
    }

    wchar_t* StrOut = (wchar_t*)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t)*(cnt1));  
    if (StrOut == NULL)
    {
        printf("Insufficient memory!\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    memset(StrOut, '\0', (size_t)(cnt1));

    for (int i = 0; i < cnt1; i++) // strcpy doesn't work
    {
        StrOut[i] = buffer[i];
    }

    if (StrOut[cnt1] != '\0')
    {
        StrOut[cnt1] = '\0';
    }

    return StrOut;
}
```

```
wchar_t* AppPath = ApplicationPath();
if (AppPath == NULL)
{
    printf("Zur\x81 \bckgegebener String war NULL.\n");
}
else
{
    printf("%S\n", AppPath);
}
free(AppPath);
```

Comment: Your `memset` is too short at least... Try `size_t bytesize = sizeof(wchar_t)*cnt1; wchar_t* StrOut = malloc(bytesize); ...; memset(StrOut, 0, bytesize);`

Comment: You are overflowing the buffer at `StrOut[cnt1] = '\0'` because you only allocated `cnt1` elements. You need `cnt1 + 1` elements.

Comment: You also don't need to clutter the code by checking if the string was already teminated. You should assume it wasn't, because the memory obtained with `malloc` is uninitialised.